# Participle II usage

Tags: word-usage

Can i use **Participle II** form of **to be** as definition?

```
The been traditions are all gone and forgotten [now].    
The been misdeeds are all forgiven and forgotten [now].
```

Can i say **the been man** in the meaning: the man who has huge experience in something?

Comment: No, that does not sound like correct English. Totally unidiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

No, neither of those sentences sounds at all correct.

---

The most faithful interpretation I can think of that does work is:

> The traditions that were are (now) all gone and forgotten.
>   The misdeeds that were are (now) all forgiven and forgotten.